# Execution time issue in CUDA benchmarks

Tags: cuda

I am trying to profile some CUDA Rodinia benchmarks, in terms of their SM and memory utilization, power consumption etc. For that, I simultaneously execute the benchmark and the profiler which essentially spawns a pthread to profile the GPU execution using NVML library.

The issue is that the execution time of a benchmark, is much higher( about 3 times) in case I do not invoke the profiler along with it, than the case when the benchmark is executing with the profiler. The frequency scaling governor for the CPU is userspace so I do not think that frequency of the CPU is changing. Is it due to the flickering in GPU frequency?
Below is the code for the profiler.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nvml.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#define NUM_THREADS     1

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
  // printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);

nvmlReturn_t result;
nvmlDevice_t device;
nvmlUtilization_t utilization;
nvmlClockType_t jok;
unsigned int device_count, i,powergpu,clo;
char version[80];
result = nvmlInit();
result = nvmlSystemGetDriverVersion(version,80);
printf("\n Driver version: %s \n\n", version);
result = nvmlDeviceGetCount(&device_count);
printf("Found %d device%s\n\n", device_count,
device_count != 1 ? "s" : "");
printf("Listing devices:\n");
result = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0, &device);

while(1)

{
result = nvmlDeviceGetPowerUsage(device,&powergpu );
result = nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates(device, &utilization);
printf("\n%d\n",powergpu);




        if (result == NVML_SUCCESS)
        {
           printf("%d\n",  utilization.gpu);
           printf("%d\n",  utilization.memory);
        }
result=nvmlDeviceGetClockInfo(device,NVML_CLOCK_SM,&clo);
if(result==NVML_SUCCESS)
{
printf("%d\n",clo);
}
usleep(500000);
}


pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: The GPU can require a significant amount of time to be ready to process work when it is in a idle or sleep state.  When you run your "profiler code", you are pulling the GPU out of the sleep state, and so probably your benchmark runs quicker.  You've given so little data in this question that it's tough to surmise what is going on, or even what your observation is.  You could try setting the GPU into persistence mode which should have a similar effect as running the "profiler code".   By the way, you donn't seem to be accepting any answers on your previous questions.

Comment: As @RobertCrovella said, try to set your GPU into persistence mode: thus, the NVIDIA drivers stays loaded when no active clients are connected to the GPU, and you avoid significant GPU initialization overhead. On Linux, this can be achieved by doing `nvidia-smi -pm 1` (`0` to deactivate it). Your GPU might not support this option.

Comment: Robert Crovella- Does setting the GPU into persistence mode using nvidia-smi requires root access? I have accepted your answers on previous questions.I wasn't aware that such a thing existed.

Comment: according to the man page (`man nvidia-smi`) yes, it requires root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your profiler running, the GPU(s) are being pulled out of their sleep state  (due to the access to the `nvml` API, which is querying data from the GPUs).  This makes them respond much more quickly to a CUDA application, and so the application appears to run "faster" if you time the entire application execution (e.g. using the linux `time` command).

One solution is to place the GPUs in "persistence mode" with the `nvidia-smi` command (use `nvidia-smi --help` to get command line help).

Another solution would be to do the timing from within the application, and exclude the CUDA start-up time from the timing measurement, perhaps by executing a cuda command such as `cudaFree(0);` prior to the start of timing.